# Can't get powershell to handle a SQL Server connection failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, smo

I am deliberately trying to log in to a SQL Server where I do not have a login to test some error handling with PowerShell 2.0 and SMO using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here's my script:

```
param ([String]$instanceName);
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null;

$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection ; 
$conn.LoginSecure = $true; 
$conn.ServerInstance = $instanceName ; 
$conn.NonPooledConnection = $true ;  

try {
    $serverInstance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server ($conn) ; 
}

catch { 
    $err = $Error[0].Exception ; 
    write-host "Error caught: "  $err.Message ; 
    continue ; 
} ; 

Write-Output $serverInstance.Version;
```

the catch block does not get executed. Any ideas? I also tried to trap it using the `trap` function, but got the same result.

**UPDATE 1**

I have changed my script to the following and have got it to catch an exception on line

```
foreach($j in $serverInstance.Databases) {
```

If I comment out the foreach loop, **the line below the foreach loop does not raise an exception**, although it should (IMO).

```
param ([String]$instanceName);

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null; # load the SMO assembly
clear

 $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    $conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection ; 
    $conn.LoginSecure = $false; 
    $conn.Login = "sa" ; 
    $conn.Password = "password" ; 
    $conn.ServerInstance = $instanceName ; 
    $conn.NonPooledConnection = $true ;  

try {
    $serverInstance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server ($conn) ; 
    foreach($j in $serverInstance.Databases) { 
        write-host $j.name ; 
    } ; 
    Write-Output $serverInstance.Databases.Count;
}

catch [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException] {
    $err = $Error[0].Exception ; 
    write-host "Error caught: "  $err.Message ; 
    while ( $err.InnerException )    {
        $err = $err.InnerException;
        Write-Host "Inner exception:" $err.InnerException.Message;
        };      
    return;
} ;
```

Comment: SMO [opens a connection when required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162132.aspx) and nothing in your `try` block actually connects to the server. Does moving your `Write-Output` command into the `try` block cause an error?

Comment: @Pondlife moving the `$serverInstance.Version` to the `try` block does not cause an error. I get the same behaviour.

Comment: I've added an updated script to my question under heading UPDATE 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround. Microsoft have confirmed this as a bug in SMO and they do not deem it important enough to fix for now. The workaround is detailed here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/636401/smo-is-inconsistent-when-raising-errors-for-login-faliures#

Comment: Microsoft Connect is retired and the link no longer works